# Make an unmanaged type ComVisible(true) when assembly:ComVisible(false)

Tags: .net, visual-c++, com, c++-cli

Given the following code:

```
#pragma unmanaged
public struct PluginHeader { };

#pragma managed
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
[assembly:ComVisible(false)];

[ComVisible(true)]
public interface class
ILHMPluginLoader
{
    bool LoadSensorPlugin (PluginHeader* pluginHeader);
};
```

tlbexp will fail to make `ILHMPluginLoader` available through COM because `PluginHeader` is not public. It issues the following warning:

> TX801311B0 Warning: Non COM visible value type 'PluginHeader' is being referenced either from the type currently being exported or from one of its base types.

However, if I make the entire assembly visible `assembly:ComVisible(true)` everything works just fine. I can't explicitly mark `PluginHeader` ComVisible(true) since it's on the unmanaged side.

How can I make `PluginHeader` COM visible without exposing the entire assembly?

Comment: TlbExp works with the whole assembly ComVisible, but can you add the .tlb as a reference to, say, a C# project?

Comment: I import and use the .tlb from a regular C++ project without issue.

Comment: try `public value struct PluginHeader { };` decorated with ComVisible instead

Comment: It is a bit of a quirk induced by the way the C++/CLI compiler emits metadata.  Even though it is an unmanaged struct, it still adds the type definition to the metadata.  But it is non-functional, just an opaque value type with no members.  However good enough to get the type library exporter to emit a declaration for it when you export everything in the assembly and thus suppress the warning.  Still non-functional, no members.  You might as well declare the argument as `void*`.  This is pretty iffy of course, you can't get a guarantee that the client code generates the proper struct.

Comment: @HansPassant So there's no way to get the compiler to emit a declaration if the assembly isn't defaulted to ComVisible? Unfortunately it's not a warning that can be ignored since tlbexp won't generate info for `LoadSensorPlugin` if the native type isn't visible. Luckily this is only ever touched by my own code so I don't have to worry much about native definitions not matching. I actually ran into this in the process of changing void pointers to typed pointers for my own sake.

Comment: It is a bit of a corner-case, a C++ project would normally use a IDL file.  But you probably won't like that either, the support for CCWs is pretty convenient.  Do beware the consequence, your wrapper is likely to survive for a very long time, the GC doesn't run very often in a scenario like this and you can't get a decent signal that the client program made its last Release() call.  If your native code uses a lot of memory then you need GC::AddMemoryPressure().  Simon's recommendation is a decent workaround, that's what a C# project would do.

Comment: I've come back to this recently to 'straighten things up' a bit. I don't reckon you use the chat feature here on StackOverflow @HansPassant?